# Рекурсия в python

Tags: python, python-3.x, рекурсия

Объясните пожалуйста, почему функция countDown(5) выводит результат от 0 до 5? То есть как она доходит до значения 0 понятно, но откуда берутся значения 1, 2, 3, 4, 5???

```
def countDown(start):
    if start <= 0:
        print(start)
    else:
        countDown(start - 1)
        print(start)
```

За счет чего происходит присваивание start новых значений?

Comment: поставьте `print(start)` - первой строкой функции и сами все поймете... ;)

Comment: за счет аргумента функции countDown - рекурсия жеж ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот более менее неплохой ответ который мне дали в одном из сообществ. Делаю репост на случай если кто-то будет искать ответ на такой же вопрос:

> Рекурсия - это как матрешка. Когда в первый раз происходит запуск, start=5, доходит до момента запуска внутри функции, и этот момент как бы запоминается. Когда выполнится функция внутри в первый раз, то основная функция продолжит свое выполнение и сделает print. Почему print выведет пять? Потому как каждый раз, когда запускается новая функция (как матрешка в матрешке), создается новая область видимости. А питон, когда идет обращение к переменной, в первую очередь смотрит в локальной области видимости - в рамках запущенной функции. И в этих рамках запущенной функции start будет равен пяти. Потому как все остальные функции (все остальные матрешки внутри этой "основной" функции) уже перестали выполняться.
>
> В первый раз запускается функция, start=5, ничего не выводится. Второй раз запускается функция. Снова ничего не выводится, т.к. перед print идет запуск очередной копии функции. Но при этом start уже равен 4, и так далее, до нуля. В разделе if else срабатывает первое условие, и очередной запуск функции не происходит. А происходит простой print нуля. После чего функция (та, самая маленькая матрешка), заканчивает свое действие. Как только эта функция закончила действие (выведя ноль), в дело вступает функция перед ней, и единственное действие, которое осталось выполнить - это печать start. В локальной зоне видимости этой функции start=1, она и выводит эту единичку и прекращает выполнение. Как только она прекратила выполняться, за дело берется предыдущая функция, которая выводит двойку и так далее по матрешке наверх, до самой большой матрешки, где start=5

Comment: чтобы понять рекурсию, нужно сначала понять рекурсию :)

Answer (score 2):

Смотрите:

- Когда вы запускаете рекурсивную функцию, она при своей работе будет "проваливаться" в себя же (`[1]`) до тех пор пока есть вызов ее же.
- У вас есть условие (`[2]`) которое ограничивает вызовы функции.
- И самое главное -- у вас функция проваливается в себя (`[1]`) до того как будет выводить значение `start`.

А это значит, что:

- Функция проваливается в себя до тех пор пока значение `start` не станет `0` и напечатает значение `start`
- Начинается выход из функций начиная с самой последней (у которой `0`) с последующим выводом `start`

Код:

```
def countDown(start):
    if start <= 0:            # [2]
        print(start)
    else:
        countDown(start - 1)  # [1]
        print(start)
```

---

Думаю, нагляднее будет если добавлю немного логирования:

```
def countDown(start, indent=0):
    print('    ' * indent, 'start:', start)

    if start <= 0:
        print('    ' * indent, 'print:', start)
    else:
        countDown(start - 1, indent + 1)
        print('    ' * indent, 'print:', start)

countDown(3)
```

Консоль:

```
 start: 3
     start: 2
         start: 1
             start: 0
             print: 0
         print: 1
     print: 2
 print: 3
```

Comment: я правильно понимаю, что если функция была в рекурсии, то она будет выходить из нее не сразу, а из области видимости в область видимости выполняя основное условие без дополнительных на это указаний?

Comment: Да, именно так. Еще пример: у вас есть несколько вложенных друг в друга `if`'ов. Код при выполнении будет входить от первого до самого последнего if. Когда завершится последний If, управление перейдет к предпоследнему, потом к пред-предпоследнему и так до самого первого.